# Phonegap Consume Webservice

Tags: cordova

Good night,

I am doing a test with phonegap to consume a webservice.

I'm using ajax for information towards a path of php, but not me lets read the json that sends as response.

Checking the console of firebug saw the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujs39.png)

And does not show me json response

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you post snippet of code with complete error ?

Answer (score 0):

In php I did the webservice. The code is this:

```
$SqlStat = "SELECT * FROM table";
$response = mysql_query($SqlStat);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($response)){
    $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

And in javascript this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://webservice.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
         data: "accion="+ruta,
        success: function(data) {
            json = $.parseJSON(data.d);         
            alert(json);
        },
        error: function(error){
         alert('error');
       }
    });
```

I see the json response with firebug, but I can read it.